# Generating dynamic SQL where clause from Scala collection

Tags: scala, collections, scala-collections

I want to generate a dynamic SQL `where` clause from a Scala collection, such as Map

Example, with a `Map("firstName" -> "Chuck", "lastName" -> "Norris")` object,
I want to generate the following clause:

```
where firstName = 'Chuck'
and lastName = 'Norris'
```

Basically, for the first element in the collection, precede with the `where` keyword, and for the subsequent ones, precede with `and`.

I'm really struggling to do this algorithm in Scala, so I'm asking for your help.
Maybe `Map` isn't the right collection for this task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible solution is:

```
myMap.map {case (k, v) => """%s = '%s'""".format(k, v)}
  .mkString("where ", "\nand ", "")
```

The `map` function with the format transform key/values into `key = 'value'`, and `mkString` build the where clause.

Comment: Being new to functional programming, this looks really magical to me. But it works... crazy!

Comment: If it's loook magical, take the time to look at the scala collections and to understand it, it's quite common scala code.

Answer (score 3):

And, because someone needs to say it, for gods sake don't do anything like this in production code!  This sort of thing is just begging for an SQL injection attack, where someone gives you corrupt input which you blindly format into SQL that does drastically different things than what you want.  Here's an example: http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're generating actual SQL statements, you may want to look at more robust models for database access. My favorite is [Squeryl](http://squeryl.org/), but there are other flavors.

Comment: indeed, another flavor is ScalaQuery ;-), and its successor, SLICK, comes this summer